# Why does the same control look differently in other window, it is blurry

Tags: wpf, fonts

Please, help, cause i'm totally insane. i have some wpf control (it contains some buttons) and it is used in different windows. in main window it looks blurry, in child window - it's ok. WHY?

Can anyone help me with my trouble?

[image: Blurry font]

P.S. Windows 7, .net 3.5 Framework

Comment: set main & child window property `UseLayoutRounding="True"` in xaml

Comment: Is it resized in main window?

Comment: ebattulga, this property is not available in 3.5 framework.

Comment: milter, yep, it's stretched within a grid

Comment: sorry i could have asked that at once... So, is the text a bitmap image or is it rendered by the control? If it's text of the control try resizing it to the size of the one in the child window and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with Anti Aliasing.

Set [SnapsToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) to true on the MainWindow.

Comment: i've added this property to main window, but fonts are still blurry